# unresolved reference -intelliJ Kotlin programs

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, syntax-error

I want to learn kotlin and started using intelliJ as IDE, but my first program ran into error "Error: Could not find or load main class "
Also it shows problems like "Unresolved reference: print"
I dont know what I am doing wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFUvc.png)

Comment: your error not about print function check your intelliJ  IDE configuration your screen shot show kotlin not configured

Answer (score 0):

just start new project
[image: starting new project]

Choose Kotlin, console app, build system (choose Intellij)
[image: choosing]

Writing code in folder src/main/kotlin/Main.kt

[image: writing code]

Then don't forget to build app

[image: build]

Run it!

[image: run it]

[image: run it!]

result

[image: result]